# How to include nmath.h?

Tags: r

I would like to include the header `nmath.h` for my `C` code (within an `R` package) to find `R_FINITE` and `ML_ERR_return_NAN`. I found that one cannot include `nmath.h` directly. For `R_FINITE` to be found, I could include `R_ext/libextern.h`. But I don't know what to include so that `ML_ERR_return_NAN` is found. Any ideas? I found [here](http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-help/052p4t6514/r-include-c-functions-from-nmath-in-my-own-c-functions) that Prof. Brian Ripley referred to Writing R Extensions, but I couldn't find `nmath.h` being addressed there (where exactly?)

Comment: See section 6.16 [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Debian or Ubuntu:

```
 sudo apt-get install r-mathlib
```

after which you can build test programs such as this:

```
// -*- mode: C++; c-indent-level: 4; c-basic-offset: 4; 
//          compile-command: "gcc -s -Wall -O3 \
//               -I/usr/share/R/include -o rmath_rnorm \
//               rmath_rnorm.c -lRmath -lm" -*-

// Compare to 
//    $ Rscript -e "RNGkind('Marsaglia'); \
//                 .Random.seed[2:3] <- c(123L, 456L); rnorm(2)"
//    [1] -0.2934974 -0.3343770

#include <stdio.h>

#define MATHLIB_STANDALONE 1
#include <Rmath.h>

int main(void) {

    set_seed(123, 456);
    printf("rnorm: %f %f\n", rnorm(0.0, 1.0), rnorm(0.0, 1.0));

    return 0;
}
```

*Note:* The first four lines should be one-line in the file you safe, then `M-x compile` build the program for your.  Ditto for the `Rscript` invocation: one line.

**Edit:** Drats. Answered the wrong question :)  `nmath.h` appears to not be exported from `src/nmath/nmath.h` *but* this R Mathlibrary is what *is* exported by R Core for use by others.  Where as the `nmath.h` file has

```
/* Private header file for use during compilation of Mathlib */
#ifndef MATHLIB_PRIVATE_H
#define MATHLIB_PRIVATE_H
```

so you are not supposed to rely on it.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks for helping. I installed `r-mathlib` and use `#define MATHLIB_STANDALONE 1` in the header file to my C code, but I still get `foo.c:13:40: error: ‘ML_ERR_return_NAN’ undeclared (first use in this function)`. Is `ML_ERR_return_NAN` then named differently? I feel this is quite a bit more technical then I thought. Essentially, I would like to use line 46 in `./src/nmath/rgeom.c` in C code for some package. The line is `if (!R_FINITE(p) || p <= 0 || p > 1) ML_ERR_return_NAN;`

Comment: One could do this check in R before calling the C code, but I
would like to compare run times with the implementation of
`rgeom()` and thus wanted to replicated this line in my C code as
well. Since this is all for a package, I would ideally not want
the user to be forced to install Mathlib (clearly, no problem on
Linux, but on Windows/Mac?)... seems to be overhead for just an
input check.

Comment: Did you see where I say _that you are not supposed to use nmath.h_ directly.   If you write a package, you may have to _copy_ what you need.  There is a difference between _public R interfaces_ and internals. You are currently lusting after the latter.

Comment: Hi... I slowly start to realize that... so functions like `rgeom` are provided in Mathlib and the C code is contained in R's source but you are not supposed to use the corresponding Macros or whatever comes with it... I could probably (not tested though) call C_rgeom() (?) as R does; see ./src/library/stats/R/distn.R.

Comment: You also get them (as object code) via Rmathlib and Rcpp offers them as well (scalar as in R's C API and vectorized via Sugar).